# Autocomplete - MaterialUI - Controled component doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Basically, I created the autocomplete component and set default value as my state `this.state.quest.ansType`, but when I change this state, the component result an error: *component is changing the default value state of an uncontrolled Autocomplete after being initialized. To suppress this warning opt to use a controlled Autocomplete.*

I need this for my update function. When the user selects the register on the database, I will load the options saved on the default value of Autocomplete.

```js
const ansTypes = [
    {
        id: 'T',
        desc: "Texto"
    },
    {
        id: 'M',
        desc: "Multipla Escolha"
    },
    {
        id: 'U',
        desc: "Escolha Única"
    },
];

<Autocomplete className="cb" id={"ansType"} options={ansTypes}
    disableCloseOnSelect
    onChange={obj => this.selectAnsType(obj)}
    defaultValue={this.state.quest.ansType}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.desc}
    renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                checked={selected}
                color={"primary"}
            />
            {option.desc}
        </React.Fragment>
    )}
    renderInput={(params) => (<TextField {...params} label={"Answer Type"} />)}
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you've been changing the default value after the first render, which shouldn't happen. Either you use an uncontrolled Component (-onChange, -value,+defaultValue, +ref) of you use a controlled component (+onChange, +value, -defaultValue, ref->only if needed).
DefaultValue should be used for the uncontrolled ones!

### Controlled

```js
...


<Autocomplete className="cb" id={"ansType"} options={ansTypes}
    ...
    onChange={obj => this.selectAnsType(obj)}
    value={this.state.quest.ansType}
    ...
/>
```

### Uncontrolled

```js
...
defaultAnsType={...};

myUncontrolledAutocomplete=React.createRef();

<Autocomplete className="cb" id={"ansType"} options={ansTypes}
    ...
    defaultValue={this.defaultAnsType}
    ref={this.myUncontrolledAutocomplete}
    ...
/>
```

$

### Personal Opinion

I'd use the controlled one, because it's easier to understand. On the other hand the uncontrolled component could make your component *stateless* which could be something you might wanna use in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Unfortunately the controlled didn't work for me, but the uncontrolled component works graeat.

Comment: I'm happy I could help you! Close the question, if possible :)

Comment: Your answer is very clear for me to understand. Thank you.